# Show a custom tooltip for a group of rectangles (points on a graph)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a `Canvas` on which I have drawn a number of `Rectangles` which represent a number of user selected positions on the canvas.

I want to create a `ToolTip` for each of the rectangles that shows the  x and y coords of the rectangle and also the distance to another point: the "stylus point".

The x and y coords are known when a rectangle is created of course but the distance to the stylus point is not therefore the tooltip needs to update its text each time it is shown.

I've tried using a binding as below but this just puts the text "System.Windows.Control.ToolTip" in the tool tip.

```
    ...

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle
    {
        Width = _rectWidth,
        Height = _rectWidth,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
    };

    rectangle.ToolTip = new ToolTip();
    Binding binding = new Binding()
    {
        Source = this,
        Path = new PropertyPath("ToolTipBinding"),
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    };

    BindingOperations.SetBinding( rectangle.ToolTip as ToolTip ,ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, binding);
}

public string ToolTipBinding 
{
    get
    {
        return "How would i get the data context here (even if it bound correctly)";
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I have a Canvas on which I have drawn a number of Rectangles` - delete all that and use proper DataBinding with an ItemsControl.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks i think I have a working solution with ItemsControl now will add answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've come up with. this will show a list of points as squares on a canvas.`TargetList`below is a list of `Target` objects that contain the required data for each point. Hope this helps someone.

Resource created for the ToolTips:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="X:" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=PositionX}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Z:" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=PositionZ}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="ΔX:" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DeltaX}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="ΔZ:" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DeltaZ}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
<UserControl.Resources>
```

Items control

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ClipToBounds="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TargetList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=PositionScreen.X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=PositionScreen.Z}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding RectangleSize}" 
                       Height="{Binding RectangleSize}" 
                       Fill="{Binding RectangleBrush}" >
                <Rectangle.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip />
                </Rectangle.ToolTip>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Target class, showing the property names only. These are updated as required.

```
public class Target : ObservableObject
{
    public Point3D PositionX...

    public Point3D PositionZ...

    public double DeltaX...

    public double DeltaZ...

    public Point3D PositionScreen...

    public double RectangleSize...

    public Brush RectangleBrush...

}
```